# iOS looping error

Tags: ios, facebook, loops, azure

So I'm having a weird problem with loops in while developing in iOS. There are over hundreds of lines of code, so instead of boring you with it, I'm going to describe the problem.

I am trying to upload events from Facebook to an Microsoft Azure server. To do so, I made a class called FacebookUploader. In that class, I loop through the events of Facebook (and set all the variables to the class. ie. the name of the first event is self.event, when loops continues and goes to the second event, that events name is self.event now). What I **expected** iOS to do was to go through each event in the loop, upload it, and then move onto the next one.

This worked while I was just uploading the event. Now, I'm also first checking the database to see if the event is already there. And then when I get confirmation that it's not there, I upload it. However, when it comes time to upload it, Facebook Uploader has already finished looping through all the events and only the last event gets uploaded (multiple times, one for each event that should be uploaded).

I've pinpointed the error, now I'm asking, what am I doing wrong? Should the variable not be associated with the class and instead be local? Or is there a way to stop running the loop until we get confirmation from the server that the event is not there? Your help is much appreciated.

```
MSQuery *query = [self.table queryWithPredicate: [NSPredicate    predicateWithFormat:@"fb_id == %@", self.id]];
[query readWithCompletion:^(MSQueryResult *result, NSError *error) {
//not in table, add it
NSArray *items = [result.items mutableCopy];
if (items == nil || [items count] == 0) {
     NSDictionary *newItem;
     if(self.end_time != nil) {
     newItem = @{@"fb_id": self.id, @"event_name": self.name, @"event_location": self.location, @"event_start": self.start_time, @"event_end": self.end_time, @"event_description": self.descriptionOfEvent, @"picture_url": self.picture_url, @"event_latitude": self.venue_latitude, @"event_longitude": self.venue_longitude, @"popularity": self.popularity};
      }
     else {
        newItem = @{@"fb_id": self.id, @"event_name": self.name, @"event_location": self.location, @"event_start": self.start_time, @"event_description": self.descriptionOfEvent, @"picture_url": self.picture_url, @"event_latitude": self.venue_latitude, @"event_longitude": self.venue_longitude, @"popularity": self.popularity};
     }
     [self.table insert:newItem completion:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
     // The result contains the new item that was inserted,
     // depending on your server scripts it may have additional or modified
     // data compared to what was passed to the server.
     if(error) {
           NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Todo Item: %@", [result objectForKey:@"event_name"]);
     }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Please add some code - it sounds like you are executing code asynchronously but not waiting for it to complete before moving to another step or

Comment: Thank you for responding. I added the code where I am connecting the server. This is where I believe the loop is not waiting for the code to finish before moving on.

Comment: That code looks OK - you haven't shown a loop and you said that is where you are having a problem - so you need to show more code

Comment: A common cause of getting multiple copies of one object when you are looping is if you allocate the object outside the loop and then reset properties inside the loop - because you are continually modifying the same instance you get the final values only

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question was given by Paulw11 above. By allocating the variables outside of the loop, I was creating multiple copies of the variables, causing my error. Allocating the variable inside of the loop fixed the error.